# SSRS email Subscription Using Exchange server 2010

Tags: reportingservices-2005, exchange-server-2010

Can it is possible to sent SSRS (SQL SERVER REPORTING SERVICE) 2005 email subscription using Microsoft Exchange server 2010 instead of SMTP? If possible than how?

We have tried to do it by editing the file rsreportserver.config.

We had change the below section of the code:

```
 <Extension Name="Report Server Email" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.EmailDeliveryProvider.EmailProvider,ReportingServicesEmailDeliveryProvider"> 
                    <MaxRetries>3</MaxRetries> 
                    <SecondsBeforeRetry>900</SecondsBeforeRetry> 
                    <Configuration> 
                         <RSEmailDPConfiguration> 
                              <SMTPServer>xxx.xx.xx.xxx</SMTPServer> //Ip Address
                              <SMTPServerPort></SMTPServerPort> 
                              <SMTPAccountName></SMTPAccountName> 
                              <SMTPConnectionTimeout></SMTPConnectionTimeout> 
                              <SMTPServerPickupDirectory></SMTPServerPickupDirectory> 
                              <SMTPUseSSL></SMTPUseSSL> 
                              <SendUsing>2</SendUsing> 
                              <SMTPAuthenticate></SMTPAuthenticate> 
                              <From>Custom-Reports@abc.com</From> 
                              <EmbeddedRenderFormats> 
                                   <RenderingExtension>MHTML</RenderingExtension> 
                              </EmbeddedRenderFormats> 
                              <PrivilegedUserRenderFormats></PrivilegedUserRenderFormats> 
                              <ExcludedRenderFormats> 
                                   <RenderingExtension>HTMLOWC</RenderingExtension> 
                                   <RenderingExtension>NULL</RenderingExtension> 
                                   <RenderingExtension>RGDI</RenderingExtension> 
                              </ExcludedRenderFormats> 
                              <SendEmailToUserAlias>True</SendEmailToUserAlias> 
                              <DefaultHostName></DefaultHostName> 
                              <PermittedHosts></PermittedHosts> 
                         </RSEmailDPConfiguration> 
                    </Configuration> 
               </Extension>
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, looking through the documentation, it looks as though SSRS can't be configured to use Exchange Web Services, [even in SQL Server 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159155.aspx).

Pretty weak.  It's as though they pretty much stopped any significant development of SSRS the day it went live.